# comparison of n custom list/collections using linq vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-objects

I am trying to compare n no of custom lists and remove the matching records from each list i.e.

```
Public Class User

    Protected _UserId As String
    Protected _UserName As String
    Protected _Email As String
    Protected _Address As String

    Public Property UserId() As String
        Get
            Return _UserId
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _UserId = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property UserName() As String
        Get
            Return _UserName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _UserName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Email() As String
        Get
            Return _Email
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Email = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Address() As String
        Get
            Return _Address
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Address = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

now I have n List(of User) in another List, so its like List(of List(of User))

```
ListMain-List1 : 

UserId      UserName      Email             Address
1           ABC           abc@hello.com     test123


ListMain-List2 : 

UserId      UserName      Email             Address
1           ABC           abc@hello.com     test123


ListMain-List3 : 

UserId      UserName      Email             Address 
1           ABC           abc@hello.com     test123
2           PQR           pqr@hello.com     test123 
3           XYZ           xyz@hello.com     test123
```

Upto list n

Now I need to check all lists items for count. If count is same among all mail list items `(MainUserList(0).UserList.Count = MainUserList(1).UserList.Count = MainUserList(2).UserList.Count)` then compare them.

If any field among any list is different them return false/some indicator.

I checked Intersect/Expect/Join but I am not sure how to take this approach and device this algo as no of Items in main list is n i.e. variable so how to loop through it and them may be use linq join to check equality...

Any help will be appreciated... Thanks!!!

Edit : The o/p of the data will be exact same lists as their count mismatch.

Consider following data set

```
ListMain-List1 : 

UserId      UserName      Email             Address
1           ABC           abc@hello.com     test123


ListMain-List2 : 

UserId      UserName      Email             Address
1           ABC           abc@hello.com     test123


ListMain-List3 : 

UserId      UserName      Email             Address 
1           ABC           abc@hello.com     test123
```

It should Indicate they are same and remove this record(s) from all the lists

hope its more clear now...

Also the exact structure is like below :

```
MainList
    Child1
         UserInfo
             Users as List(of User)
    Child2
         UserInfo
             Users as List(of User)
    Child3
         UserInfo
             Users as List(of User)
    Child4
         UserInfo
             Users as List(of User)
    Childn
         UserInfo
             Users as List(of User)
```

Modified the code...

```
Dim IsUser As Boolean
IsUser = _userList.All(Function(x) x.UserInfo.Users.Count > 0)
Dim userCount As Integer = 0
Dim userGroupCount As Integer = 0


If (IsUser) Then

    Dim firstCount = _userList.First().UserInfo.Users.Count
    Dim allSameLength = _userList.All(Function(x) x.UserInfo.Users.Count = firstCount)

    Dim allSame = False
    If allSameLength Then
        ' Combine the lists, and group all the Users by key values
        Dim groups = _userList.SelectMany(Function(x) x.UserInfo.Users) _
            .GroupBy(Function(x) New With {Key x.UserId, Key x.UserName, Key x.Email, Key x.address}).ToList()

' Each group should have one item for each original list. If not, there
        ' are different `key`s in the lists (assuming there were no dups in
        ' the original lists).

        For Each objBase As Object In _userList
            userCount += objBase.UserInfo.Users.Count
        Next

        userGroupCount = groups.Count()

        Dim sameUsers = IIf(userCount = userGroupCount, True, False)

        If sameUsers Then
            ' All PMs in each group should be equal
            'allSame = groups.All(Function(x) x.All(Function(y) y.Equals(x.First())))
        End If
    End If

End If
```

But its still incomplete without the final result set....

Comment: Your users need to have a unique ID, which could be username. Otherwise your comparison will yield false results, if one list has records 1 and 2, and another has 2 and 1. 1 does not equal 2, 2 does not equal 1, no matches. What are you trying to do? In other words, what's the business value for comparing users in your case?

Comment: Looking again, it looks like maybe I ignored the first line in your question when I came up with my answer below, but I'm not entirely sure what is being asked. I left the answer there in case it gets you something close to what you want, but please clarify your question if I was totally off base!

Comment: Thanks @Mark for the reply. If you are taking about this first line **compare n no of custom lists and remove the matching records from each list** then I will update my question with what exact o/p I seek.

Comment: @NikhilGupta So, the result should be that the lists contain only the users that are not identical in all of the lists?

Comment: @Mark, if count is same them compare the values and if any row found same among all them remove it from all the user lists. So lists should contain nonidentical values

Comment: @Mark there is no unique key in the User class. Also I have added the structure of the main list in the post. I am getting error **Public member 'All' on type 'List(Of IGrouping(Of VB$AnonymousType_0(Of String,String,String,String),User))' not found.** on line **Dim sameUsers = groups.All(Function(x) x.Count = MainUserList.Count)** Also I have changed the group by line as **Dim groups = MainUserList.SelectMany(Function(x) x.UserList) _
        .GroupBy(Function(x) New With {key x.UserId, key x.UserName, key x.Email, key x.Address}).ToList()**

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want correctly, you can check if all of the lists in `MainUserList` have the same length with something like this, which just checks that all the lists have the same length as the first list:

```
Dim firstCount = MainUserList.First().UserList.Count
Dim allSameLength = MainUserList.All(Function(x) x.UserList.Count = firstCount)
```

For the other checks, the best I could come up with is to combine all the `User`s from all of the lists, and group them by `UserId`.  If everything is the same then the number of `User`s in each group should be the same as the number of original lists, and all the `User`s in each group should be `Equal`:

```
Dim allSame = False
If allSameLength Then
    ' Combine the lists, and group all the Users by ID
    Dim groups = MainUserList.SelectMany(Function(x) x.UserList) _
        .GroupBy(Function(x) x.UserId).ToList()
    ' Each group should have one item for each original list. If not, there
    ' are different `UserId`s in the lists (assuming there were no dups in
    ' the original lists).
    Dim sameUsers = groups.All(Function(x) x.Count = MainUserList.Count)
    If sameUsers Then
        ' All Users in each group should be equal
        allSame = groups.All(Function(x) x.All(Function(y) y.Equals(x.First())))
    End If
End If
```

You will need to override the `Equals` method in your `User` class for this to work, or change the comparison above:

```
Public Overrides Function Equals(other As Object) As Boolean
    If other Is Me Then
        Return True
    End If
    Dim otherUser = TryCast(other, User)
    If otherUser Is Nothing Then
        Return False
    End If
    Return Me.UserId = otherUser.UserId _
        AndAlso Me.UserName = otherUser.UserName _
        AndAlso Me.Email = otherUser.Email _
        AndAlso Me.Address = otherUser.Address
End Function
```